# Pandas XML: How to read the second line?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I read the second line of XML files where the value of interest looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

xml1 = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Inventory SchemaVersion="1.0" ItemID="TestItem">
  <SpecificDeviceGroup>
    <Device Count="2" Description="Base System Device">
      <HardwareIDs>
        <ID Value="testvaluehere" />
      </HardwareIDs>
    </Device>
    <Device Count="1" Description="PCI Express" Class="System">
      <HardwareIDs>
        <ID Value="testvaluehere2" />
      </HardwareIDs>
    </Device>
</SpecificDeviceGroup>
</Inventory>
'''
```

This try fails

```
# fails
pd.read_xml(xml1, xpath = ".//Inventory")
```

Here is the expected value

```
# expected
TestItem
```

Comment: Why would you use pandas for this, instead of the built-in XML package like `xml.etree`?

Comment: Seems like you're missing a dot? `pd.read_xml(xml1, xpath="..//Inventory")`